# ArcGIS Enterprise - referring to a layout file in a data store

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-portal, arcgis-enterprise, arcgis-data-store

I've set up a data store in my Portal - it refers to a location on the hard drive of the machine that is hosting the Portal, basically using "//localhost/c%/myfolder". I've named it something simple, "LayoutStorage".

According to ESRI's documentation, I should be able to drag files into there and they'll be available for my server to use. I've copied a layout pagx file there.

Now, I'm trying to access it in my code but cannot - I get an error saying:

> RuntimeError: Missing or invalid layout template file

This is the code I'm trying to run (note that `data` is a json to a webmap, and the code works without trying to use this templatepath:

```
templatePath = "//https://MyServerHere/LayoutStorage/layout002.pagx"
result = arcpy.mp.ConvertWebMapToArcGISProject(data, templatePath)
```

The code I'm referencing is used multiple times here: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/convertwebmaptoarcgisproject.htm

Comment: Can you copy the exact path you've used in your data store directory? Your example path is ripe with problems. If you're indeed using a UNC share, it should look like `\\myserver\LayoutStorage` AND it needs to be shared to the account running ArcGIS Server. When you do a verify data store connection, does it give you a green check mark?

Comment: After verifying the path location -- you're trying to retrieve the `pagx` over an HTTP connection. Is this actually a web server enabled location? If you've set the data store up correctly, the template path should point to the same location as you set in your data store. Then in the code, combine the two paths.

Comment: @KHibma thanks for your help so far. I've created a folder on my server's c:\ called Datastore_Layouts (so c:\Datastore_Layouts). In Portal, I've created a folder data store to \\localhost\Datastore_Layouts (all verified). My code is linking now to `templatePath = "\\myserver.com\LayoutTryAgain"` (where LayoutTryAgain is the data store name). I'm still getting a _"Missing or invalid layout template file"_ error.

Comment: You put the file on the server, so if there a reason why you're using a network path to reference it? Doing so means you need to have both SHARE and SECURITY permissions explicitly granted to the account running server. Otherwise, if you use a local reference (`c:\DataStore_layouts)`, then you only need to grant the SECURITY permissions to the server user.

Comment: Excellent, that worked (after a fashion - turned out another issue was that I upgraded ArcGIS Pro to 3.0, but didn't upgrade my server to 11 - as such, the layout file wasn't working. Rather than upgrade my server I downgraded ArcGIS Pro). Please feel free to write up an answer that I'll accept.

Comment: @user25730 Are you trying to create a custom print service? Do you need to keep the PAGX file in a datastore folder? We're having issues getting custom print templates to work and wondering if a Data Store folder is required.